# How to return one of the in-parameters in gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I thought this sounded simple enough but i cannot seem to figure out how to do it.. I'm mocking a linux socket interface using this mock function:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD4(send, int(int socketDescriptor, const void* buffer, size_t n, int flags));
```

I want to return the number of bytes written with `send`.

One idea was this:

```
  uint32_t nBytes = 0;

  EXPECT_CALL(socketMock, send(124, _, _, MSG_NOSIGNAL))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<2>(&nBytes),
                    Return(nBytes)));
```

But this will always return zero.

What should i do instead to `Return(Arg<2>)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [CheatSheat](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md) it looks like this is what you want:

```
EXPECT_CALL(socketMock, send(124, _, _, MSG_NOSIGNAL))
    .WillOnce(::testing::ReturnArg<2>()));
```

Comment: No problem. I'm just familiarizing myself with GTest and GMock. :)

Comment: FWIW, Depending on compiler warnings, this will produce a warning as the in param is a size_t and the return type is an int.

Comment: @bgura This issue is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958796/gmock-removing-implicit-conversion-warning-when-using-returnarg

Comment: But in the question there is a `Return(nBytes)`. Where is this in the answer?