# GMock removing implicit conversion warning when using ReturnArg

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, googletest, googlemock

Given the following mock method

```
MOCK_METHOD2(send, int(const void* pBuffer, size_t szBuffer));
```

And the following usage

```
EXPECT_CALL(socketMock, send(_, _))
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(ReturnArg<1>());
```

Will generate a warning in ReturnArg due to the implicit conversion of szBuffer into the return type of int.

Here's an example of code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class ISocket {
public:
    virtual int Send(const uint8_t* payload, const std::size_t payloadLength, std::size_t& sentLength) = 0;
};

class SocketMock : public ISocket {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD3(Send, int(const uint8_t*, const std::size_t, std::size_t&));
};

class MySender
{
public:
    static void Ping(ISocket& socket)
    {
        std::size_t bytesSent;
        uint8_t payload[64];
        memset(payload, 0, sizeof(payload));

        socket.Send(payload, sizeof(payload), bytesSent);

        if (bytesSent != sizeof(payload))
            throw std::runtime_error("Socket transmission failed");
    }
};

TEST(SocketSend, ReturnsBytesTransmitted)
{
    SocketMock socket;

    EXPECT_CALL(socket,
        Send(
            ::testing::_, // payload
            ::testing::_, // payload length
            ::testing::_  // return by param, bytes sent
        )).Times(1)
        .WillOnce(::testing::ReturnArg<1>());

    MySender::Ping(socket);

    ::testing::Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(&socket);
}

GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Here's the compiler warning:

> googletest\googlemock\include\gmock/gmock-more-actions.h(165): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data (compiling source file TestMain.cpp)

Is there anyway to make GMock use a static_cast to change the return type to eliminate the type conversion warning?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? I cannot reproduce it with this code: https://pastebin.com/raw/QFUKixdw

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534, I've updated the question with sample code that compiles and has the issue. I also added a tag of Visual Studio as I noticed I was not clear on what environment I was having this issue. I would think both *nix & windows would have a similar conversion issue though I have not validated on *nix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReturnArg<k>` is a Google Mock "action" ([reference](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/08b787796c5f18317feeb4063982a3fd3c650cfd/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#using-actions)) that returns the `k`th argument of the function being mocked. Since in this case, the return type of the function is `int` and the first argument is of type `size_t`, a warning about a potentially narrowing warning is generated.

The easiest way to inject an explicit typecast is to write a custom action:

```
    ACTION_TEMPLATE(ReturnArgWithTypeCast,
        HAS_2_TEMPLATE_PARAMS(int, k, typename, return_type),
        AND_0_VALUE_PARAMS()) {
        return static_cast<return_type>(::testing::get<k>(args));
    }
```

The action can be used this way:

```
...
.WillOnce(ReturnArgWithTypeCast<1, int>())
```

Comment: This is a great answer BUT there is a problem. Since about Nov 2020, the parameter "return_type" is used internally within the ACTION_TEMPLATE macro definition, so using this sample code as written gives weird errors. To fix them, simply change "return_type" in the code above to something else e.g. "my_return_type".